# Is there an iPod app to easily switch wifi on and off?

Tags: ipod-touch, applications, wifi

Is there an app whose only purpose would be to change the wifi prefs, by starting or stopping the wifi on iPod Touch? I would like to have an icon on the home page, and a simple click on it will switch the state of the wifi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through the App Store? No. Apple's guidelines don't allow apps to turn on or off Wifi.

Jailbroken? Yes. There are program such as [SBSettings](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/sbsettings) that will do just what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you're running iOS 4+ you can go to the Settings icon and then there's the 'Flight mode' option at the top which does just that. Not as a simple as you were hoping for, but it is just a click and a swipe.

I have a Linksys WAG160N which my iPod disagrees with so I frequently have to reset my wifi this way, and it's much quicker than the old iOS 3 workflow.

Comment: You might be able to reset your Wi-Fi connection via locking/unlocking your iPod, that's how [I got it working on my iPad](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/06/ipad-tip-quickly-reconnect-to-wi-fi-via.html).