# Is there an iOS app for quick switching of the wifi network?

Tags: ios, applications, wifi

On my iPad, I frequently need to switch between two wifi networks due to different access rights on those networks. It's quite cumbersome having to navigate to the Settings App, find the network settings page, and switch networks there. I'm looking for an app that helps me speed up the network switching, by either:

- offering a list of available networks, ideally as a notification center widget, and allows me to select a network there; or
- offers a quick link to opening the relevant page in the Settings App.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are a few jailbreak tweaks that can do what you want, though. So if you're on iOS 9.0.2 or lower, you can try that out.

Comment: iOS 9.1 jailbreak came out today, just so you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No to toggling two preset networks. Siri can toggle WiFi and Apple provides fast access via the control center.

- Swipe down from off screen top right corner
- Tap and hold WiFi
- Tap and hold WiFi
- Choose a (new) SSID

[image: control center details from iPadOS 13.6.1]

Answer (score 5):

No, [iOS applications do not have access to Wi-Fi settings](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1592/is-there-an-ipod-app-to-easily-switch-wifi-on-and-off) and basically [all other settings](https://workflow.is/faq#q2).

Answer (score 1):

You can actually access WIFI directly via the Notification Center / widgets such as Launcher from Cromulent Labs or Magic Launcher widget. They offer the option to open up WIFI from the widget without going to the Settings app first. This has been working from iOS8 untill iOS10. Unfortunately you can't however switch within the widget itself between WIFI access points it's only a quick link that bring you to the WIFI area of the Settings app.

Ofcourse you can also access cellular data this way or switch between bluetooth devices quickly via such a widget.