# How do I automatically enable Personal Hotspot when my Bluetooth device is in range? (Similar to Tasker for Android)

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, tethering, automation

I use a spare smartphone with no SIM card as a navigation tool in my car.
This works fine with offline maps, but I can't use things like [Waze](https://www.waze.com/). I also have an iPhone which I carry around with me, which does have a SIM card.

I wanted to know if there was a way to have the iPhone automatically start its Personal Hotspot tethering when it sees the other phone is in range via Bluetooth.

This would allow data access to the SIM-free smartphone only while I was in my car, which would be a perfect solution similar to what the [Tasker app on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) can do. Perhaps something like the [Workflow app](https://workflow.is/) would help?

Comment: Still on iOS 15 - the shortcuts automation should be able to trigger on a Bluetooth device connecting but not yet able to toggle the on/off status of the personal hotspot. What did you choose as a workaround here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a way to do this if you're jailbroken with tweak called [Activator](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/libactivator/) by [Ryan Petrich](https://twitter.com/rpetrich), and unfortunately it's the only solution because regular [App Store apps aren't allowed to access settings like Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, and Personal Hotspot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/228722/18387) (even [Workflow cannot access them](https://workflow.is/faq#q2)).

If you happen to be jailbroken, the way to do this with Activator is to go `Settings > Bluetooth > On` then `Settings > Activator > Anywhere > Bluetooth Devices > Connected to [your Bluetooth device]` and assign it to `Switches > Hotspot`. You might also want to assign the `Disconnected from [your Bluetooth device]` event to the same action, so when you connect Bluetooth, your hotspot turns on, and when you disconnect Bluetooth, your hotspot turns off. If `Switches > Hotspot` doesn't appear in the list of available assignments, then you'll also need to install [Flipswitch](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.a3tweaks.flipswitch/) by the same author.

For use on iOS 9 and 10, see Doron Gold's comment below on how to set it up.

Comment: This does not work because by just enabling the Hotspot switch via Activator, the iPhone does not start broadcasting its hotspot. The only way I could find to make the iPhone start broadcasting is to go into Settings --> Personal Hotspot. This is true even if you always leave the Personal Hotspot switch on. Unfortunately, this means there is no way to have non-Apple devices connect to the iPhone's Hotspot automatically. I would be happy to be proven wrong :)

Comment: @DoronGold I used to use Activator and Flipswitch for enabling Personal Hotspot. Maybe it doesn't work anymore? You could try contacting Ryan Petrich and seeing if he knows about that.

Comment: I solved it: install [Activate Link](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/org.rdharris.activatelink/). Go to `Settings > Activate Link`, next to `Link 1` type: `prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING`. Create a bluetooth connection trigger as described in the answer above, but instead of assigning `Switches > Hotspot`, assign `Activate Link 1`.  
Now when you connect to your car's Bluetooth, the Personal Hotspot screen will open, and the iphone will actually broadcast its wifi.
On **iOS 10** the url [might need](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42266843/2591231) to start with "App-Prefs:" (instead of "prefs:").

Comment: @DoronGold Awesome! I'll update my answer to have people look at your comment for iOS 10.

Comment: I'm actually using my solution on iOS 9. I don't have iOS 10 installed yet. I only mentioned that on iOS 10 Apple seems to have changed the prefix of their builtin URL schemes (prefs > App-Prefs). I learned this from other comments but haven't actually tried to run anything on iOS 10 myself.
As I mentioned in my first comment, your solution didn't work for me on **iOS 9**. Only having Activator automatically open the Personal Hotspot screen did the trick.

Comment: You can do this natively now with “Shortcuts”, see this great write up: https://www.reddit.com/r/CarAV/s/QNugsJyAO7

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in vanilla iOS.

EDIT: Here's a Stack Overflow question that proves that there is no API for it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860673/is-it-possible-to-programatically-enable-hotspot-mode-in-iphone)

If there is no API, unless Apple provides the functionality it can't happen. And Apple does not provide any method of doing this as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please add links to sources on the internet that back up this assertion, or describe steps you took to try to accomplish the same thing. One line 'answers' have a very short lifetime on AskDifferent.